# Final int parameter used in anonymous Runnable

Tags: java, android, final, runnable

I am wondering if I use correct method to call something in different thread.
I am doing it on Android, but think it is generic Java question.

I have method with some parameters. Lets say they are int.

```
class Main1 {
  public static void mainOnlyWork(int x, int y) {
     // not important here.
  }
}

class Test {
  Handler mHandler;

  // called from main thread, stored as reference.
  public Test() {
    mHandler = new Handler();
  }

  public static void callInMainThread(final int x, final int y) {
    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        Main1.mainOnlyWork(x, y);
      }
    });
  }
```

Now my question is, is it safe to use final ints to create anonymous runnable without any class members? If I omit final keywords for x and y parameters, Eclipse will complain. It seems to me, that is intended to use only constant numbers in such cases. If I pass not a constant, is it ok? Does Java "make" it constant by passing to this function?

But I want to call Test.callInMainThread from native using JNI. There is no way Java can tell if those numbers are constants or not in my opinion. Can I trust Java to make some magic? Will it always work this way?

I think maybe I have to create proxy class, like:

```
private abstract RunnableXY implements Runnable {
  public RunnableXY(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }

  public int x;
  public int y;

  public abstract void run();
}
```

And call method would use:

```
  public static void callInMainThread(final int x, final int y) {
    mHandler.post(new RunnableXY(x,y) {
      public void run() {
        Main1.mainOnlyWork(this.x, this.y);
      }
    });
  }
```

This way, i protect values against garbage collecting until runnable is used and dropped away. Do I have to create wrappers, or is marking final x in method parameters safe? When I try it, final keyword works just fine. However in threads, I do not think if it works now is reason it will work always as well. Does it work always with final? How is it made if it does? Would there be difference if parameter is not primitive type, but Object?

Update:
I already understand what final means in Java. That is not point of question. Point of question is where is scope of variables used in creation of Runnable. They are locals, that means after end of function their value cannot be referenced. Where are that values stored then, when Runnable object is passed to other thread and waits to be executed?

Comment: I think i have found answer myself. Those parameters has to be final, because they are then used when generating run() method of anonymous Runnable. If I run callInMainThread(x=3, y=5), public void run() will have generated body as Main1.mainOnlyWork(3, 5), not referencing any variable, local or global. This is what I was seeking. It is stored in code of Runnable.run() that is created at that point. And code will not change when passing between threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with the basics: Java makes *copies* when you pass parameters. The x and y that your method receives are not the original variables that are passed in, they are copies of the original values. When you declare a method like this the values that you pass in don't have to be constants, but the copies that the method receives are<sup>1</sup>:

```
callInMainThread(final int x, final int y) { ..... }
```

Second: No, you don't have to make wrappers. When you access variables that are local to the outside scope the Java compiler automatically generates fields to store them, just like the wrappers you created manually. This is transparent to you.

One reason why you can't omit `final` is because Java doesn't implement any mechanism for transferring changes to the value of the variable between the local variable of the method and the generated field in the anonymous class. Also, the anonymous class may live longer than the method call. What happens if the anonymous class reads or writes the variable after the method has returned? If the variable is not final you can't read its value anymore or write into it.

---

<sup>1</sup> Actually `final` variables are not constants. You can assign different values to them but only once. The value of final method parameters is assigned when the method is called, so they are pretty much constant for the duration of the method.

Comment: Ah, thanks! I did not understand what exactly were meant by third paragraph, until I figured it myself in different words.

Answer (score 3):

Internally a copy of parameters and local variables (residing on the method call stack) is taken in the thread. This is because after the method call is finished, the thread still lives.

And the variables are required to be final, to forbid overwriting the original variables in the method, which would cause having a different version in the thread. Which is simply misleading. So it is a matter of letting both versions of the same name mean the same thing.

*Careful language design.*

*(Simplified somewhat, not naming symmetrically reversed cases, where the same holds.)*

Answer (score 1):

Primitives types are always passed by value. Even if you modify them inside a method, their original values (outside the method) are never changed. So yes, it is safe because these values are local to the method (be them `final` or not).

About `final` keyword in parameters, it actually only impedes you from re-assigning the value, it has no other purpose. This is for mere code safety. Parameters are **always** passed by value in Java (object references are passed by value too), so no matter what, any re-assigning will be local to the method. Once the method has finished, all re-assigning you've done in the method will fade away. For example, there's no difference between

```
public void test(String a) {
    a = "Hello";
}
```

and

```
public void test(final String a) {
    a = "Hello";
}
```

except that compiler will raise an error in the second case. In first case when `test()` method finishes `a` will be restored to original value (it will not be *"Hello"*). So effectively final in parameters make the parameter "constant" (watch out that for objects: you can still modify the object state, but not the reference of the object).

---

`final` keyword is required in anonymous classes because you're referencing a variable in another class scope (in your case, your anonymous `Runnable` instance is referencing `Main1` instance variables). So if this is run in another thread and they're not final, you could overwrite the original reference for the duration of the method. This will make each thread reference different objects with same variable name, which is confusing, and thus it was blocked in the language design.

---

You don't have to create any wrappers or additional references. Parameters are already referenced for the duration of the method and will not be garbage-collected.

Comment: Exactly fact they are local to function worries me. If I call it three times with different parameters, fast in row. Before main thread will start executing first function, method parameters were changed 3 times. Where are stored that local values? If in local thread stack, it should be possible it will be overwritten. Main thread must not access worker thread stack, right? Are those ints in heap memory that is shared between threads?

Comment: Local variables are stored in stack because they're temporary storage. Each thread has its own stack, it's not shared. This is thread's local context. They cannot be overwritten in local thread stack except by current thread context, no matter how fast they are called or from where - in fact I cannot understand what you exactly mean by this. Also, again, this values are **copied**, so no matter if they change in local scope, you're exclusively changing that local copy and not another copy and not the original value.

Comment: Then my question is how are they copied into new Runnable() {}. Are they made as fields of that anonymous object? I want to know how those variables are sent to the other thread. I understand what means local variable. But those variables are not used when that method is called. They are passed to method, that will be called in future. Where are they in time between?

Comment: The Runnable is also created when you call that method. So the values the Runnable uses will be the values passed to the method because the anonymous class is inside that scope. How they're copied to the anonymous interface actually depends on Java's implementation of anonymous classes/interfaces. IMHO this is irrelevant: copied as fields, or whatever. You can check the JRE source code if you really want to know the details.

Comment: It is what I am asking for. Does Java/Dalvik make sure variables are always intact and how does it do that? Irrelevant it may be if I am sure VM makes sure they will never be overwritten or invalid. I am not skilled enough to understand JRE source and understand whether it is safe or not. I hope someone wiser will know.

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean by *"make sure variables are always intact"*. A `final` variable cannot be changed, this is checked at compile time. Again: parameters are a copy, local context can modify this in any way it wants, it won't affect other threads' same variable. *"how does it do that"* Read the source code. If you don't have knowledge to understand JRE source, then you won't understand how it does it. Anyway, *how* is actually pretty much irrelevant. Besides this might be implemented in different ways depending on JRE developer. You can assume the JRE is doing it right.